# htaccess rewrite first page of pagination to original url

Tags: .htaccess, pagination, url-rewriting

I'd like to use htaccess to rewrite or redirect all urls that have the string Page-1- and make them go to the original url. e.g.

original url : http://www.website.com/blahblah

assuming the above url is a category with many pages and user has gone to page 2 and through that page he/she wants to return to page 1. As it is now, hitting page 1 at the pagination list , it will take him/her to

http://www.website.com/blahblah/Page-1- (number of results per page)

I'd like to make all urls with Page-1- go to the original url instead

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Page-1- /$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with QSA

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Page-1- /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```